# Script question: Form submitting but not redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

For some reason, when I press the "submit" button, the form is submitted but I am not redirected to the checkout page. I understand there can be a canceling when a submit button is combined with "window.location.href", but I'm not sure why and how to fix this issue. Below is the code. Any help would be immensely appreciated! Also, this code seems to work fine on a pc, but not on my iphone. No idea why or if that's just coincidence.

```js
$(document.body).on('submit', 'form.vulpines-wcpv-shortcode-registration-form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formEl = document.querySelector('.vulpines-wcpv-shortcode-registration-form');
  var fd = new FormData(formEl);

  var form = $(this);
  var form_items = form.serialize();

  fd.append('action', 'wc_product_vendors_registration');
  fd.append('ajaxRegistrationNonce', wcpv_registration_local.ajaxRegistrationNonce);
  fd.append('form_items', form_items);

  // clear all messages firscot
  $('.wcpv-registration-message').remove();

  form.block({
    message: null,
    overlayCSS: {
      background: '#fff',
      opacity: 0.6
    }
  });

  var request = $.ajax({
    url: wcpv_registration_local.ajaxurl,
    data: fd,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  });

  request.done(function(response) {
    form.unblock();

    if (response.length && 'success' === response) {
      $(document.body).trigger('wcpv_vendor_registration_on_success');

      form.before('<p class="wcpv-shortcode-registration-success wcpv-registration-message">' + wcpv_registration_local.success + '</p>');
      form.fadeOut('fast');

      // clear all fields
      $('input, textarea', form).not('input[type="submit"]').val('');

      // redirect to the checkout page.
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "https://vulpines.net/checkout/?add-to-cart=1701";
      }, 1000);



    } else {
      var errors = '';

      $.each(response.errors, function(index, value) {
        errors += '<span class="error">' + value + '</span>';
      });

      form.before('<div class="wcpv-shortcode-registration-form-errors wcpv-registration-message">' + errors + '</div');

    }

    $('html, body').scrollTop(topOfForm.top - 50);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row">
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="vendors" tabindex="8" />
</p>
```

Comment: Please show the complete code of the submit action. you likely need a preventDefault unless you do want to submit the form

Comment: I uploaded the button code as well. Is there anything off the top of your head you could see wrong with it? I was reading that window.location.href can cause problems with submit buttons, but I don't know of any work around.

Comment: I added the complete submit action code. I do want to submit the form, I just need it to redirect to the checkout page once submitted, but the redirect isnt working on iphones (possibly all mobile devices)

Comment: @mplungjan any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I will look later. It’s 5:30am here

Comment: @mplungjan did you have a chance to look it over yet?

Comment: Sorry, I wil look now

Comment: I updated your question with a snippet. Please add the form, at least the form tags

Comment: Are you loading this form from `https://vulpines.net/` if so, WHY use Ajax at all. Whyn not just submit the form and have the server redirect to https://vulpines.net/checkout/?add-to-cart=1701 ???

Comment: @mplungjan We would be willing to do that! This form was created, and we're trying to edit it. For some reason it works fine on all devices but iOS. What would be a good way to have the server redirect to that url? We're confused as to why its working on every platform but iOS.

Comment: Just do a server redirect

Comment: I'd suggest setting up Apple's Simulator to test iOS mobile Safari. Here is an article, which might be out-of-date, that should help you get started. https://www.viget.com/articles/set-up-simulator-and-test-ios-mobile-safari-on-mac/ Many web browsers come with Developer Tools that allow you emulate mobile devices. Here an an article discussing that https://www.digitalcitizen.life/emulate-mobile-device-desktop-browser/ I'd start with the mobile device emulation to see if that catches what might be occurring. At minimum you'll be able to capture the requests/responses to see what's happening.